# Software Center shows none of my purchases

Tags: software-center

On both my Chrubuntu Acer C7 laptop, and on my desktop box, this week, the Software Center shows a blank screen when I select "Reinstall previous purchases." In other words, it says that I have no purchases at all.

I "purchased" a couple of free programs in the For Purchase menu, so I could verify that my username & password were valid. Both times, it asked for my Launchpad ID & password, accepted them, and downloaded & installed the program. Then I selected "Reinstall previous purchases." Another blank screen.

Does ANYONE have a reason or solution for this?

Comment: Did you upgrade to the development version (13.10) of Ubuntu last week?

Comment: I have the same issue! And previous purchases are not installable (after direct search). It seems this is a problem with my account. I tested it on Ubuntu 13.04 / 12.10 and 12.04. Always the same.

Comment: No, both of my machines are running 13.04.

Answer (score 1):

A bug report has been filed for this.  It seems that a relatively small amount of people are affected by this.

[Link to bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/software-center/+bug/1198779)